# Android Studio how to create 16 new Path at once?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am required to create 16 new Path in my current project, and set up each one individually one by one. I am wondering if there is a way to simlutaneously create 16 new Path at once ?

```
// Instantiate 16 Paths
Path outLine1 = new Path();
Path outLine2 = new Path();
Path outLine3 = new Path();
Path outLine4 = new Path();
Path outLine5 = new Path();
Path outLine6 = new Path();
Path outLine7 = new Path();
Path outLine8 = new Path();
Path outLine9 = new Path();
Path outLine10 = new Path();
Path outLine11 = new Path();
Path outLine12 = new Path();
Path outLine13 = new Path();
Path outLine14 = new Path();
Path outLine15 = new Path();
Path outLine16 = new Path();

// Setting up all the path one by one
outLine1.moveTo(0, 0);
outLine1.lineTo(100, 100);
outLine1.lineTo(100, 0);
outLine1.close();

outLine2.moveTo(100, 100);
outLine2.lineTo(200, 200);
outLine2.lineTo(200, 100);
outLine2.close();
```

I am wondering if anyone got a way to simplify this ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
For (i=0;i<=15;i++)
    Path outLine[i] = new Path();
```

Comment: That's invalid syntax.